# Reduce a List<T> to a sublist of itself

Tags: c#, generic-list

How can I achieve the equivalent of

```
// myList is a List<T>

myList = myList.GetRange(offset, number);
```

as an in-place statement? (i.e. without creating a new list in the process)

Comment: No, but the "old" list will get garbage-collected pretty quickly if necessary.

Comment: `myList.RemoveRange()`

Comment: To be more helpful, what is the exact problem you're trying to solve. Is the list massive and copying it is slow? Do you need a physical list or could you use an iterator that only takes the items you want?

Comment: `myList.RemoveRange(offset + number, myList.Count - (offset + number));` followed by `myList.RemoveRange(0, offset);`

Comment: One operation (creating a new list) should be in general case faster than two operations (2x RemoveRange), which BTW internally copy data anyway. Why OP wants to avoid creating a new list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> without creating a new list

How about enumerating the result of a LINQ Skip/Take:

```
myList.Skip(offset).Take(number);
```

If you're looking to make permanent alterations to the list:

```
myList.RemoveRange(offset+number, myList.Count - (offset+number));
myList.RemoveRange(0, offset);
```

You might find that it's faster to make a new list than remove from an existing one; if you're doing this for performance reasons, be sure to race your horses

Comment: That does not modify the initial list, and it does not give you a list, but an iterator. If you add `ToList()` it will have the same functional impact as the original.

Comment: Right, but I'm assuming the intention is *not* to call `ToList()` -- if you just want to enumerate the results but don't need to materialise them in memory

Comment: The way I understand it is that his `myList` variable should afterwards refer to a list with just the subrange, but he does not actually want to point to a *new* list. So the question is to do the equivalent *manipulation* of the list.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach to update the list in-place:

```
myList.RemoveRange(0, offset); // Remove items at the beginning
myList.RemoveRange(count, myList.Count - count); // Remove items at the end
```

This has `O(n)` complexity, where `n` = `myList.Count - count`.

Answer (score 0):

Not really possible due to how List handles its internal array.
Another "problem" is that the new List would have Add, Remove etc. How would those affect the original List?

Depending on how this new "slice" is to be used... maybe an IReadOnlyList facade would be appropriate?
Inject the List, Offset, Number. Implement the methods using the args to offset into the inner List indexer... (with protections for the range being greater than List.Count etc)
You'd need to implement an enumerator with the same offset, but that's pretty easy with `yield`

Answer (score 0):

Or...
`CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan(myList).Slice(offset, number);`
will give you a Span over the internal array. This has an enumerator, indexer, count.

Still need to take care that offset+range is not greater than Capacity. And it'll get "tricky" if the Capacity of the List changes to intersect the span. As List will create a new array, but your span will still be over the old one.

Another "careful what you wish for" situation :)